# action not happening when adding input dialog box

Tags: java, input

I was working on my screenshot method. I have added naming the screenshot now, i made the box pop up and where you can type the name in but once i type in the name 
and press ok i get no error. But it does not save 
this is the new code i have

```
public void takeScreenshot() {
    try {

        Window window = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusedWindow();
        Point point = window.getLocationOnScreen();
        int x = (int)point.getX();
        int y = (int)point.getY();
        int w = window.getWidth();
        int h = window.getHeight();
        Robot robot = new Robot(window.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice());
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage bufferedimage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
                    String sn;
                    sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name Yout Screenshot");
        File file = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(SignLink.getCacheDirectory() + "Screenshots/" + sn + " ").append(".png").toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the code i had when it worked

```
public void takeScreenshot() {
    try {
        Window window = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusedWindow();
        Point point = window.getLocationOnScreen();
        int x = (int)point.getX();
        int y = (int)point.getY();
        int w = window.getWidth();
        int h = window.getHeight();
        Robot robot = new Robot(window.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice());
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
        java.awt.image.BufferedImage bufferedimage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
        int picNumber = random(100);
        String fileExtension = "The Iron Door";
        File file = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(SignLink.getCacheDirectory() + "Screenshots/" + fileExtension + " ").append(picNumber).append(".png").toString());
        ImageIO.write(bufferedimage, "png", file);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The only line of code that i have changed is this one

`File file = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(SignLink.getCacheDirectory() + "Screenshots/" + fileExtension + " ").append(picNumber).append(".png").toString());`

Comment: You will learn much more quickly and effectively if you take more time to debug your code yourself, rather than quickly posting your problems here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out `ImageIO.write(bufferedimage, "png", file);`